# Proper way to design sine inverter

Tags: inverter, sine

I have looked through many examples and tutorials of how to design sine wave inverter. But all those tutorials show how to make very basic inverter, which is not meant to be used for any load. Or they use EGS002 driver.

I have tried applying PWM to transistors (basic four switch inverter), but sine wave is very poor - I get this result.

[image]

Recently I found this example:

[image]

Which use very odd PWM signal - each pair of transistors is not used for each part of amplitude, but they are used simultaneously.

[image]

And this method give very nice (nearly perfect) sine wave, but only for current. Voltage is still very bad:

[image]

This result confused me - shouldn't PWM be for one pair of transistors, then for another? Why this another method give perfect sine wave, but only for current?

Also - LC filter, as I understand, is capable of increasing voltage. Could this be used to increase output voltage, so transformer, or higher voltage input wouldn't be necessary?

I am planning on making a simple functioning sine inverter, just for my own educational purpose.

Comment: You plotted only one side of the load but you need to plot the differential voltage across the resistor: first `LClick` and keep it pressed on one side of the load resistor, then drag the cursor over to the other side of the resistor until the probe turns red, then release the right mouse button.

Comment: wow - thank you. so this actually shows the voltage for resistor (load)?